# Custom aggregate function in h2o group_by using Python

Tags: python, h2o

Is there a way to use a custom aggregate function when using group_by on h2o frame in Python? Something like:

```
frame.group_by('column').aggfun()
```

Comment: To what end? Do you have an example of what a custom aggregate function would do?

Comment: I have no specific example. Just any function (or multiple functions) acting on string/numeric vector and returning scalar (or multiple scalars) string/numeric values. I just want to know how flexible this library is.

Comment: The short answer is no, it has pre-defined aggregation methods and that's it.  The long answer is, yes! it's an object-oriented language, you can extend `frame` and `GroupBy` objects to make them do whatever you want